# Python returns none when I do have a return value

Tags: python

I'm making a refresher on recursion and i've made a python file like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys

if (len(sys.argv)!=3):
    raise ValueError('Please provide two dimensions.')
else:
    pass

def plotLand(a,b):
    if(a==b):
        print(a)
        return a
    if(a<b):
        c=b%a
        b = c if(c!=0) else a
    else:
        c = a%b
        a = c if (c!=0) else b
    plotLand(a,b)
result = plotLand(int(sys.argv[1]),int(sys.argv[2]))
print(result)
```

I added the `print(a)` just to check if my function was returning a value. I call this file in linux terminal in this way:

`python algorithms.py 1680 64`

And this is my output:

```
80
None
```

The print function inside my recursive function is printing the value, but I'm not getting the return value of the function. The original function didn't have the print function, as I mentioned before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recursive functions work exactly like non-recursive functions – if you don't write `return` and a value, you're returning `None`, and you only return anything when `a == b`.

You need

```
return plotLand(a,b)
```

I also think that you could shorten your code to

```
def plotLand(a,b):
    small, large = sorted((a,b))
    remainder = large % small
    return plotLand(remainder, small) if remainder else a
```

Comment: I think `return plotLand(small, remainder) if remainder else a` is cleaner for the final line.

Comment: @QuantumChris I agree.

Comment: I'm migrating from C# to python, that's why I made it that way, I didn't know that functions. Thank you so much, it works.

Answer (score 0):

You only return for one condition. You can consider adding a default at the end of the function